# Adding registries to Container after initialization

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

When creating a StructureMap container, I typically do something like this:

```
var container = new Container(registry => {
    registry.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>();
});
```

Where

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry {
    public MyRegistry() {
        Scan(x => {
            x.Assembly("My.Assembly.Name");
            x.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this has resulted in quite many `registry.AddRegistry` lines in a bootstrapper file, which is then copied into many projects. I would like to be able to call a method taking a constructed container and adding a registry to it, so I can modularize libraries.

I came up with this:

```
public static void Setup(ref Container container) {
    container.PluginGraph.ImportRegistry(typeof(MyRegistry));
}
```

This works, in that the registry is properly added to the container (seen by calling `container.WhatDoIHave()` before and after), but it seems the actual mappings are not done - ie the interface `IFoo` is not registered to concrete class `Foo` that both are defined in `My.Assembly.Name`.

What is the difference in doing `ImportRegistry` and `AddRegistry`? Can my `Setup` method be fixed?

Comment: Btw, there is no need to declare the container as a ref parameter.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan: Could you elaborate on why? I guess I'm misunderstanding something on the ref keyword, so it'd be great to find out what :)

Comment: You only need to use ref if you want to change the variable assignment within the method. You do NOT need it if you just want to change the object instance passed in the variable. Bottom line, unless you are doing Win32 interop, you should never use ref in C# code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try `Container.Configure()`? It exists to configure a container after it has already been initialized.